# Mysql Ranking query assignment

Tags: mysql

I want to get a table like this

Display the books we have, ranked by their page count. We want to use a 50-page range for ranking the page counts. This means that any book with page counts 500-549 have the same rank; page counts 550-599 have the same rank; page counts 600-649 have the same rank; page counts 650-699 have the same rank, etc. In the sample display we have four books which are all at rank 3. Note that we are not skipping rank numbers- examine the first two sample rows. Do not make assumptions about the maximum page count value. When designing the logic of the query. do not use the current set of data in the table to make decision about the logic.

```
+---------+------------+------+
| Book_ID | Page_count | Rank |
+---------+------------+------+
| 1001 | 2000 | 1 |
| 1587 | 1300 | 2 |
| 8546 | 982 | 3 |
| 8415 | 980 | 3 |
| 1474 | 976 | 3 |
| 1444 | 970 | 3 |
| 1524 | 918 | 4 |
| 2005 | 894 | 5 |
| 200 | 879 | 5 |
| 201 | 850 | 5 |
| 4574 | 825 | 6 |
| 6584 | 825 | 6 |
```

EDITED: Now I have

```
SELECT b.book_id AS Book_ID, b.page_count as Page_Count, (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT page_count)
FROM a_bkinfo.books as b2
WHERE b2.page_count >= b.page_count
) as Rank
FROM a_bkinfo.books as b
ORDER BY Page_Count DESC
```

Now I get this result

```
Book_ID  Page_Count Rank
1448    3192    1
1306    2895    2
1979    1368    3
1678    1002    4
1677    982     5
1689    980     6
```

I need to figure out how to do the 50 page range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
select
  book_id,
  page_count,
  (select count(distinct b2.page_count DIV 50)
   from books b2
   where b2.page_count DIV 50 >= books.page_count DIV 50) as page_rank
from books
order by page_count desc
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, it was >= instead of <= could you explain to me what DIV 50 does?

Comment: @RaymondYan, DIV is the complement to modulus, or %:  it does integer division and returns the integer part as an integer instead of a float, e.g. `SELECT 5 DIV 2` returns 2, not 2.5.

Comment: @RaymondYan DIV is the integer division, e.g. `5 DIV 2 = 2`, in your example 2000 DIV 50 is 40, 1300 DIV 50 is 26, and 982, 980, 975,970 DIV 50 are all 19